# Getting arcpy.da.walk to continue walking after encountering corrupt/problem file

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, corrupt, walk

I am relatively new to python. I am trying to iterate through all DWG polylines in a directory with multiple (hundreds) of subdirectories. I would like the code to skip any DWG files that it cannot do something to and continue iterating.

The following code works fine, until it comes across any DWG files that are possibly corrupted. Python stalls and I cannot get it to throw an exception.

I have isolated the problem to the arcpy.da.walk. It appears that the walk function can open the corrupted DWG to find the polyline, but it cannot get out of the DWG to continue the walk.

I have tried multiple exception types. I am not sure how the onerror function call works in arcpy.da.walk,or even if this is an avenue of exploration (I cannot find any examples where onerror is anything other than "NONE").

```
import arcpy  
import os  
import sys  
from arcpy import env  
import pdb  

##def WalkErr(onerror):  
##    try:  
##        import errno          
##        print errno  
##        if errno!=errno.ENOENT: raise  
##             
##        elif errno == errno.EACCES:  
##            print filename,"cannot open"           
##        else:  
##            print errno  
##            print filename, "Not Found....Continuing"  
##    except:  
##        print "Something went wrong"  


WorkspaceRoot="W:/GIS_Scratch"  

env.workspace=WorkspaceRoot  

#List workspaces in root directory  
workspaces=arcpy.ListWorkspaces ("*","Folder")  
for workspace in workspaces:  
    env.workspace=workspace  
    print workspace  

#Find workspaces named Drawings  
    workspaces1=arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*rawing*","Folder")  
    print workspaces1  

    for workspaceNext in workspaces1:          
        arcpy.env.workspace = workspaceNext  
        print workspaceNext  

#start stepping through code      
#    pdb.set_trace()  

# Walk through directory to find CAD polylines (Note: "CadDrawing" datatype does not return any polylines, so had to use "FeatureClass")  
        try:  
            for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspaceNext,topdown=True, datatype='FeatureClass',onerror=None,type='Polyline'):  
                try:  
                    print dirpath  
                    for filename in filenames:  

                        try:  

                            arcpy.env.workspace=filename  
                            desc = arcpy.Describe(dirpath)  
                            featureTest=(os.path.join(dirpath,filename))  
                            print filename  
                            print featureTest  
                            print desc.extent.XMin  
                            filename.close  

                        except arcpy.ExecuteError:  
                            arcpy.AddError(arcpy.GetMessages())  
                        except:  
                            arcpy.AddError("Non-tool error occurred")  
                except OSError as e:  
                    print e.errno  
                    print e.filename  
                    print e.strerror  
                    continue  


                except Exception as e:  
                    print "An error has occurred"  
                    print e  
                    continue  

        except OSError as e:  
            print e.errno  
            print e.filename  
            print e.strerror  
            continue  
        except Exception as e:  
            print "An error has occurred"  
            print e  
            continue
```

Comment: did you try  pass in the try..except block to see if it will keep on marching, rather than worrying about error types for now?

Comment: Dan, I have tried pass in the try..except block. I just tried it again and, unfortunately, the walk still doesn't keep marching.

Comment: How are the DWG polyline files corrupted?

Comment: You could try Pythons native os.walk instead of arcpy.da.walk to find all Dwg files.

Comment: Aaron, I am not sure how they are corrupted. The DWGs crash ARCGIS when trying to view, or use a geoprocessing tool. In python, geoprocessing tools never throw an exception, but they do not allow python to continue.

Comment: Klewis, I have tried os.walk, but then need to use arcpy to access the polylines. The result is the same.

Comment: Please post on the Esri forums or contact Esri support. This sounds like something that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Jason, Will do.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code that I used to finally solve my issue. Multiprocessing and os.walk allowed me to iterate all the DWGs within the directories.Thank you everyone for your help!

```
import os, arcpy, multiprocessing, csv, sys
outputCSV=r'W:\GIS_Scratch\MultiProcessing.csv'

#Get spatial extent of dwg files and spatial reference
def GetExtent(ds):
    desc=arcpy.Describe(ds)


    with open(outputCSV, 'a') as csvfile:
       csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
       csvwriter.writerow([ds,desc.extent.XMin,desc.extent.YMin,desc.extent.XMax,desc.extent.YMax,desc.spatialReference.name])

#Find all .dwg files in directories
def main(workspace):
    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
    dataset1 = arcpy.ListDatasets("*.dwg", "Feature")
    ds_list=[os.path.join(workspace,dataset) for dataset in dataset1]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(GetExtent,ds_list)    
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

#iterate directories
arcpy.env.workspace = "F:/Metro Design/_Rev 8, jobs"
workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces ("*","Folder")
for workspace in workspaces:
    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
    workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces ("*rawing*","Folder")
    for workspace2 in workspaces:
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(workspace2):
            for subdirname in dirnames:
                WorkspacePass = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
                if __name__=='__main__':
                    main(WorkspacePass)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use function, something like

```
def Get_Xmin(desc):
 try:
  return desc.extent.XMin
except:
  return -1
```

instead of continue

Comment: Thank you Felix. Unfortunately using the function stalls as well. ESRI support has suggested trying to use threading to open a new thread to continue if the walk is stalled for a set amount of time.